# Generate All possible combinations of Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, math

I have 2 integers, i would like to create a list of arrarys using both of these like so:

Int1 = 3
Int2 = 4

Array1(4,4,4)
Array2(4,4,3)
Array3(4,4,2)
Array4(4,4,1)
Array5(4,4,0)
Array6(4,3,4)
...
Arrayn(0,0,0)

is there an efficient way of doing this? I'm essentially generating all possible combinations of length x using y number of items.

I'm using python, but happy to use other methods!

Comment: You want to create 3-dimensional arrays with only 2 dimensions?

Comment: Have a look at [the functions in module itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Specifically `itertools.product(range(y+1), repeat=x)`

Answer (score 1):

If the words "generate" and "combinations" are in the question, then the answer is in [module itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

```py
from itertools import product

def answer(x, y):
    return product(range(y+1), repeat=x)

print( list(answer(3, 4)) )
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (0, 3, 4), (0, 4, 0), (0, 4, 1), (0, 4, 2), (0, 4, 3), (0, 4, 4), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 0), (1, 4, 1), (1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (1, 4, 4), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 0), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 4), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 0, 4), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 0), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 3), (3, 4, 4), (4, 0, 0), (4, 0, 1), (4, 0, 2), (4, 0, 3), (4, 0, 4), (4, 1, 0), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 3), (4, 1, 4), (4, 2, 0), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (4, 2, 3), (4, 2, 4), (4, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 3), (4, 3, 4), (4, 4, 0), (4, 4, 1), (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```